# onClick called without actually clicking the button

Tags: c#, monogame

Developing in Monogame I have created some simple way to detect that a sprite has been clicked. This is how I check that the sprite was pressed. `mouseOver` means the mouse is intersecting the sprite.

```
var lastMouseState = mouseState;
mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
if (mouseOver && lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
     onClick(this);
```

`onclick` is managed in another class. This class is called `Menu`

```
private void onClick(Button btn)
{
    //Toggles the button.
    if (btn.HasCheckBox)//Whether the button has a checkbox
    {
        btn.Checked = !btn.Checked;
    }
    if (btn.Destination == "inGame")
        unPause();
    else if (btn.Destination == "Quit")
        Exit();
    else
        openMenu(btn.Destination);
}
```

A little explanation here: Each button has a property called destination, meaning where the button leads to, such as: inGame, Options, Quit, etc.

Now here is my problem:

When the game is paused, the menu is shown containing 3 buttons (continue, options, and quit).

When the menu is opened and a submenu is entered, then a button there is pressed, after that, the menu is closed and the mouse has not been moved, then when I reopen the menu and the mouse is on top of the `Quit` button, the game will close. Check the gif below for a much clearer explanation.

*This only happens with `Quit`. When I try the same procedure with the other buttons, it does not work.* {SEE EDIT 2}

A small demonstration: 
http://media.giphy.com/media/AxVvk9FgO6TOd5roEo/giphy.gif

I try it first with the `music` button. close and reopen menu -- nothing happens.
I try it with the `fullscreen` button, click > close > reopen menu -- game quits.

Why is a button click registered at `quit`, but not at `options`?
Thanks for the help. Comment if additional information is needed.

---

EDIT
Apparently, it does not matter where the mouse is when entering the options menu. As long as a click is done (anywhere in the screen) and after the menuscreen is reopened the mouse is hovering over the button, the game will quit.

Strangely enough, I added a new button, under `Quit` which also leads to the options menu. After testing the same behaviors with the 2nd `Option` button. I could not reproduce the error. However, If I do the same with the 1st `Option` button while hovering the second one, it works same as with `Quit` -- it will instantly open the option screen as if it was clicked.
Updated Gif: http://media.giphy.com/media/AxVvk60pK8NBjmghDa/giphy.gif

---

EDIT 2
Narrowed the bug even further. When using foreach, the bug only appears when the index of the second button is greater than the first. Explanation: I was pressing 2nd button, `button[1]` and it was only working for `button[2]` and higher.

This is my update method:

```
if (isPaused)
{
    foreach (var button in ButtonList)
    {
        if (MenuScreen == button.Parent)//Menuscreen is the current screen being displayed.
//button.parent is the parent screen that holds current button. such as: ingame, pause, etc.
        {
            button.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I know the logic behind it, but not where it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could have some unseen characters mucking up the works, maybe from a copy paste or something. If you added another similar button and it worked, that could be a possibility.

You could re-type it by hand manually or run it through something like jsbin to see if anything shows. (In jsbin it shows red periods for unseen characters.) Just an idea to try if all else fails you.

Comment: problem only happens to buttons that have index higher than the first button. In my case it was working for `button[1]` to `button[2]`, but not to `button[0]`. And after using a backwards for loop, it was only working to indexes lower (e.g. `button[1]` to `button[0]`, and so forth)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the bug was happening because the buttons that were not visible were not being updated, which meant that their respective mouse positions were not updated -- which still doesn't explain why the index had to be greater.

Anyway, I added a conditional in the `Update` method of the button. In case this `bool` variable is true, update the clicks too. And if the buttons are not visible, or the variable is false, only the mouse states are being updated.

Solution:

```
if (isPaused)
{
    foreach (var button in ButtonList)
    {
        if (MenuScreen == button.Parent)
        {
            button.Update(true);
        }
        else 
            button.Update(false);
    }
}
```